# Not able to install iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ios7, ios5

I have developed my iPhone application using Phonegap.I am able to install my application from diawi to my development device(iPhone 5c).

Using Iphone have IOS 7.1 version and developed my application using developer certificate.

Same link on client device download the application,but application is not installed properly.The installation failed with the following error message "`Could not install the xxxx(app name) application on this device`".

Need help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Since this application is installed on your phone, certificates and provisional profiles are created properly. The error on the client device may come because of two reasons:

1. Client device UUID is not added to the provisional profile which is used while compiling this application.
2. Your deployment target is higher than client's device iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are in development phase and trying to install the app via Xcode. If thats the case then make sure 
 1. you have added Client iPhone UDID in the list of devices in the Member Center 
 2. You have included that device ID in list of devices which can install the app under your provisioning profile. 
 3. If you are using Team Provision Profile, then make sure all devices are associated with the team + all development certificates are associated with the team.  
 
 If you have already release a app then I am sure you had created a [distribution certificate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html).  
 
   Just before you submit your app to the store, you create a signed archive of your app and validate it. 
Test your final build before submitting it to the store, and if you have not done so, test the archive again for regressions after validating it. [Link 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW12)

If you are targeting a specific iOS version (for e.g.: 7), make sure client's devices has <= of that.